# Rendering specific divs in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, rendering

I have a top div (**a**) and two bottom divs (**B**, **C**).
When the top div is updated I want it to only cause rendering in div **C** and not in div **B**

how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you manage your application state. If you have local state of props in C that change in response to some action in div A then React will detect that and rerender the modified components.

It's not good practice to force React to re-render certain components. Just change your state and let React do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method in your B component.